# How to put object datefield in html input value

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, datefield

I have a class "client" with an attribute datefield called "birth_date".
I want to give the possibility for update this field.
How can i put the default value in the form, in the input type date? Because the format in "client.birth_date" is different.

```html
{{client.birth_date}} <br>
        </div class="form-group">
            <label for="birth_date">Data di Nascita:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birth_date" name="birth_date" value="{{client.birth_date}}" >
        </div>
```

[image]

If i try with, for example:

```html
 </div class="form-group">
            <label for="birth_date">Data di Nascita:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birth_date" name="birth_date" value="2018-02-01" >
        </div>
```

The input value is setting true, but the format is different from the one i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to format the date like so:

```
<input type="date" name="birth_date" id="birth_date" value="{{ client.birth_date|date:'Y-m-d' }}">
```

Or set the default date format in `settings.py`:

```
DATE_FORMAT = "Y-m-d"
```

Comment: I try with the first and it works correctly! Thank you so much